# create_users capabilities on a role on multisite

Tags: multisite, capabilities, user-roles

I'm having some issues regarding a user's capability on a multisite. So, I have a network of sites and on each site I want a role (Local Admin) to be able to create users.

I've added the capabilities to that role and added a user to that role. When I log in as the user and dump their the returned data from `get_userdata` function I see the correct role and `create_users` is set to true. However when I use `current_user_can( 'create_users', wp_get_current_user() )` I get false.

What am I missing? Are there any specific capabilities I need to add because I'm using multisite? Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem. It's easily solved by going into the Network Admin > Settings page. Look for the label "Add New Users" and make sure this option is checked: **Allow site administrators to add new users to their site via the "Users → Add New" page.**

Once you do this, the local admin will be able to add users. This is assuming they also have the capabilities `list_users` and `create_users`. I recommend this full list of related user capabilities be given:

- `list_users`
- `create_users`
- `promote_users`
- `edit_users`
- `remove_users`
- `delete_users`

Answer (score 1):

According to the Codex article on [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table), the Administrator of any site within Multisite would have the ability to create users.

With that said, why not add users as Admins instead of creating a new role and adding capabilities?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like `capabilities.php` has the following line `elseif ( is_super_admin( $user_id ) || get_site_option( 'add_new_users' ) )` which is causing my issue. I'll be having a looking further into getting `get_site_option( 'add_new_users' )` to return true.

Comment: Bear in mind that, in Multisite, any user created is created in the network, not in the individual site. Which is why (I assume) the creation of users is assigned to Super Admins in Multisite.